# Blender Collada IO Script location

Tags: scripting

I want to change some presets for the DAE Import/Export, but for the hell of it I'm not able to find the locations of wm.collada_import and wm.collada_export.

If anyone could be of quick help I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Collada presets in

```
[your install dir]\2.80\scripts\presets\operator\wm.collada_export
```

There are two files `sl_plus_open_sim_rigged.py` and `sl_plus_open_sim_static.py`

Comment: `WM_OT_collada_import` doesn't have `ot->flag |= OPTYPE_PRESET;` set in Blender's source.